# C# Applying same function to different variables

Tags: c#, linq

```
string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", var1, var2, var3)
```

I want to apply URL Encoding on each of var1, var2, and var3. It's not an array, so I can't use Linq Aggregate to do it.

Any ideas?

I would hate to have to put brackets around each of the variable.

Comment: If it's not an array what is it?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to put `UrlEncode(...)` around each argument or define a helper function, the only way is to make the implicitly created array explicit and apply the method to each element:

```
var args = new[] { var1, var2, var3 };
Array.ConvertAll(args, UrlEncode);
var result = string Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", args);
```

or

```
var args = new[] { var1, var2, var3 };
var result = string Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", args.Select(UrlEncode).ToArray());
```

or, if all you want to do is putting commas between the elements:

```
var result = string.Join(", ", new[] { var1, var2, var3 }.Select(UrlEncode));
```

---

Using a helper function:

```
var result = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", UrlEncodeAll(var1, var2, var3));
```

or

```
var result = string.Join(", ", UrlEncodeAll(var1, var2, var3));
```

where

```
string[] UrlEncodeAll(params string[] args)
{
    Array.ConvertAll(args, UrlEncode);
    return args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void EncodeAndFormat(string format, params object[] args)
{
     return string.Format(format, 
             args.Select(obj=>HttpUtility.UrlEncode(obj.ToString()).ToArray());
}


EncodeAndFormat("{0}, {1}, {2}", var1, var2, var3)
```